# Get saved locations marker from google maps account

Tags: android, google-maps, google-account

My question is for and Android app but it could be applied for anything interacting with Google Maps API.

I just want to know how to get the data of all saved location markers symbolised by stars on the official Google Maps app. My purpose is to get all this stars locations to save them in a local database.

To understand how to do it, I first need to know how to get info from a Google account and specifically the Google Maps data.

Thank you in advance,

Alexandre

Answer (score -2):

Try to save the markers object inside [`SharePreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients share. Objects that are returned from the various get methods must be treated as immutable by the application.

**Setting values in Preference:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("name", "Elena");
editor.putInt("idName", 12);
editor.commit();
```

**Retrieve data from preference:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
}
```

Here's a Demo App which save markers in Shared PReferences: http://www.androidtrainee.com/adding-multiple-marker-locations-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-and-save-it-in-shared-preferences/

Comment: The question is **how to get the data of all saved location markers symbolised by stars on the official Google Maps app**